# Why do I keep getting Script function not found: sendInvoiceIfNew when I use the initializeTrigger function?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, triggers

```
function initializeTrigger(){ 
    // run this only once to create a trigger if necessary
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    ScriptApp.newTrigger('sendInvoiceIfNew')
    .forSpreadsheet(sheet)
    .onChange()
    .create();
 }

function sendInvoiceIfNew(e){
    Logger.log(e.changeType);
    if(e.changeType=='INSERT_ROW'){
        sendEmails();
        Browser.msgBox('New row(s) added');
    }
}
```

Can someone please help me to fix this? The sendEmails function works just fine, but the summary of failures email says "Script function not found: sendInvoiceIfNew". Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you also copy and paste the HTML part of the project so we can see?

Comment: I copy-pasted to my spreadsheet, and it works without any errors. Check your list of triggers to make sure you haven't created an unwanted trigger with misspelled function name. (Also, for @Auguste: there is no HTML, this is Google Apps Script bound to a spreadsheet.)

Answer (score 0):

try creating the Spreadsheet object using sheet ID or Sheet URL.

var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("sheetId_goes_here");

 OR 
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl('sheet_url_goes_here');